# Retain Navigation buttons on iOS Progressive Web App but hide address bar

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, user-interface, mobile, progressive-web-apps

I'm using the web-app-capable meta tag in a Ruby on Rails PWA we're building. By default, this will result in address and navigation bar disappearing being hidden. Is there any way to hide the address bar, but retain Safari navigation buttons on the bottom? 
Looking to avoid having to build a 'Back' button into the header.
Thanks!

Comment: Can you show the meta tag you are using?